# Why Is Data Being Saved When Code Is Stopped Before Save Function

Tags: c#

I have a procedure in my code where it does some data validation and then calls a SAVE function. The SAVE function writes the validated data to the database. If I but a code break BEFORE the SAVE function is called and then stop debugging, the data is STILL being saved in the database (i.e. the SAVE function is STILL being run). I validated this because if I comment out the call to the SAVE function, and do the same as described above, nothing gets saved.
Here is an example of my code:

```
protected bool Savedata()
{
    string newpostingid = "";
    bool isSaved;
    int SaveError = 0;
    postingid = 0;
    string description = "";
    string RequiredSkills = "";
    string Certifications = "";
    string Travel = "";
    string duration = "";
    string WIIFY = "";
    string postingdate = "1/1/2000";
    DateTime? fromdate = validate_date(From_Date.Text);
    DateTime? todate = validate_date(To_Date.Text);
    DateTime? startdate = validate_date(Start_Date.Text);
    if (RequiredSkillsTextBox.Text != "") { RequiredSkills = RequiredSkillsTextBox.Text; }
    if (CertificationsTextBox.Text != "") { Certifications = CertificationsTextBox.Text; }
    if (WIIFYTextBox.Text != "") { WIIFY = WIIFYTextBox.Text; }
    newpostingid =
    jdh.UpdatePosting(
        Convert.ToInt32(OpportunityTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue),//PostingTypeID
        Server.HtmlEncode(OpportunityTitleTextBox.Text),//PostingTitle
        Convert.ToInt32(SalaryGradeDropDownList.SelectedValue),//SalaryGrade
        Convert.ToInt32(DisciplineDropDownList.SelectedValue),//LOBMFOID
        );
)
```

In the above code snippet, If I put a break BEFORE the newpostingid = jdh.UpdatePosting, and stop debugging when it hits the break, the newpostingid = jdh.UpdatePosting still gets called. As I indicated above, commenting out the newpostingid section, nothing gets saved when I stop debugging.

Comment: How're you stopping debugging?

Comment: try using shift + F5

Comment: How do you call ```Savedata()```?  If you're spawning new threads then you may have another thread working that data; although it would still hit the break point, it may or may not die when you stop debugging.  If there's a lock mechanism in place then when you stop debugging you release the lock and the waiting thread runs it. (This is theory because I have no idea how you're calling it.)

Comment: Let me clarify since I miss-typed. I put a BREAKPOINT (i.e red dot shows on the line). I stop debugging by hitting the RED SQUARE (Stop Debugging Icon). The SaveData is being called from a button click event. I'm not explicitly creating any threads.

Comment: Very strange. Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the `UpdatePosting` method, or logging something to the console inside that method?

Comment: Also worth checking the Threads window (`Debug > Windows > Threads`) to check you only have one thread running when you hit the breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

To Start Debugging you usually use the green Play Icon or <kbd>F5</kbd>

If you put a Breakpoint anywhere in your code, the debugger stops the execution there.

It only pauses the execution and doesnt stop it, thats why the correct Terminus for it is **Breakpoint** not **Break**. The line will be marked Red and a Red dot will appear at the lefthand side of your line.

However to Stop the Debugging, you will need to eiter press the `Stop Debugging` Button or 
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> which will do the same.

You can use `Step Into` <kbd>F10</kbd> or `Step Over` <kbd>F11</kbd> to step by step proceed the code execution. If you press <kbd>F5</kbd> while debugging, it will proceed to the next Breakpoint or until the end of your program execution.

Hope this helps with your struggles.

Comment: Let me clarify since I miss-typed. I put a BREAKPOINT (i.e red dot shows on the line). I stop debugging by hitting the RED SQUARE (Stop Debugging Icon). Let me also add I start the debugging by selecting the Green Arrow Internet Explorer button in the toolbar.

Comment: @FlyFish well, try putting a Breakpoint inside `jdh.UpdatePosting()` to see if it gets called elsewhere. Anyway, try improving your Question with a [mcve] then, so we can reproduce your problem, as it seems not to be a trivial usage problem.

Comment: also use the Parallel Stacks window (Ctrl + Shift + D, S) to see parallel executions.

Comment: I checked using Threads and Parallel Stacks windows. There is only a single thread and no parallel stacks (It shows just the single thread/process. I'll see if I can come up with a simple example, but it may be hard. The jdh.updateposting is a call to a helper class that handles the actual database interactions. I'm not sure how to provide a simplification of this entire process of capturing form data, passing it the save function and then passing the validated data to the helper, where someone else could reproduce. Suggestions?

Comment: well if there's no parralel executions, im almost sure you're using Visual Studio in some odd manor :). But yea, its somehow difficult to write a Question ([ask]), but if you're 100% sure that you're not using VS wrong, and it won't be saved, if you comment out the section, It's propably a Bug in VS. Even though I very highly doubt that. Can't tell you more lad. Maybe step through the whole function with F10 and see when it saves? Maybe it's being saved before the Breakpoint. Can't tell without more code.

Comment: even if it was a Bug in vs, you'd have to make a [mcve] for the VS-Dev team to reproduce and fix it. So do it anyway.

Comment: And yea, If I helped you in any way make sure to give some credits :)